# Why can't my interceptor block certain URLs?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat, jakarta-ee

```
/** WebMvcConfig.class */
@Override
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    registry.addInterceptor(new WebSecurityConfig())
            .addPathPatterns("/**")
            .excludePathPatterns("/login","/loginPost");
    super.addInterceptors(registry);
}
/** WebSecurityConfig.class */
@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
    boolean flag =true;
    User user=(User)request.getSession().getAttribute("user");
    if(null==user){
        response.sendRedirect("/login");
        flag = false;
    }
    return flag;
}
```

I added an interceptor that jumps to the login page when the user is not logged in. The interceptor works when I enter 'http://localhost:8011/git/vision'. But when I type this URL, 'http://localhost:8011/git/vision/index.html', the interceptor doesn't work. It means that I can access this resource without logging in. Can you help me solve this problem?

Comment: Which version of spring-boot are you using ?

Comment: The version of spring-boot is 1.5.9.